# Best way to clean an array and insert a new element

Tags: react-redux

I want to know what the best way to clean an array would be, write a new element.
My array, selectedUser, will be nurtured with the information I send as payload, after clicking on a row in the table.
You should always have only one element in the array, so I must delete the information it contains when selecting another element. I am currently doing it as follows, but I don't think it's the right one.

```
import * as actionTypes from "../actions/userModuleActions";
const initialState = {
  selectedUser: []
};
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  state.selectedUser = [];
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.UPDATE_USER_MODULE_SELECTED_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        selectedUser: state.selectedUser.concat(action.payload)
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default reducer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case since you are completely replacing the old value with the new you can  replace the `selectedUser` key in `state` entirely:

```
import * as actionTypes from "../actions/userModuleActions";
const initialState = {
  selectedUser: []
};
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.UPDATE_USER_MODULE_SELECTED_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        selectedUser: [action.payload], // note that action.payload is wrapped in []
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default reducer;
```

No need to "clear" the `selectedUser` first.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using another data type for storing the selected user? Maybe you should create a SelectedUser model with attributes and set its initial state to undefined.

Comment: The table component that I am using, mui-datatables, returns the data of the selected row as an array. If what I intend to do is very complicated, I will have to follow your suggestion and make conversions.